# While loop prints one line twice when validating if string is double ( Basic Calculator )

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm writing Assignment on basic calculator and my code seems to be perfect but it has one bug.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Define new Scanner

    String answer = "yes";
    double finalValue;

    while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {

    System.out.print("Enter First Number: ");
    String firstNumber = scanner.next(); // Define first number, and ask user for input

    while (!firstNumber.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter number only: ");
        firstNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter an operator (+, -, / or *): ");
    char operator = scanner.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.print("Enter Second Number: ");
    String secondNumber = scanner.next();

    while (!secondNumber.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter number only: ");
        secondNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    switch(operator) {
    case '+':
        finalValue = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber) + Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        System.out.println(finalValue);
        break;
    case '-':
        finalValue = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber) - Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        System.out.println(finalValue);
        break;
    case '*':
        finalValue = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber) * Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        System.out.println(finalValue);
        break;
    case '/':
        if(secondNumber.equals("0")) {
            System.out.println("a number can not be divided by 0.");
        } else {
        finalValue = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber) / Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        System.out.println(finalValue);
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Operator entered incorrectly.");
        break;
    }

    System.out.print("Do you want another operation? (type yes to continue): ");
    answer = scanner.next();

    }

    System.out.println("Bye.");


}
}
```

When I compile it and input some word instead of number in firstNumber or secondNumber, it outputs "Please enter number only: " twice for the first time and then once. I tried my best to solve it but I can't please help :(

Comment: Do you use an IDE like Idea or Eclipse? Because you could easily debug your code and find out yourself what it does. See [how to debug with eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) and [how to debug with idea](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that you could solve this by using `scanner.nextLine()` every time, and do not use `scanner.next()`. I reworked your code and it's working now. May I inquire why you don't make use of `scanner.nextDouble()`? Anyway, see code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Define new Scanner

        String answer = "yes";
        double finalValue;

        while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {

            System.out.print("Enter First Number: ");
            Double firstNumber = null;
            while (firstNumber == null) {
                try {
                        firstNumber = Double.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter number only.");
                }
            }

            System.out.print("Enter an operator (+, -, / or *): ");
            String line = null;
            while (line == null || line.length() == 0) {
                line = scanner.nextLine();
            }
            char operator = line.charAt(0);

            System.out.print("Enter Second Number: ");

            Double secondNumber = null;
            while (secondNumber == null) {
                try {
                        secondNumber = Double.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
                } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter number only.");
                    secondNumber = null;
                    scanner.reset();
                }
            }

            switch(operator) {
                case '+':
                    finalValue = firstNumber + secondNumber;
                    System.out.println(finalValue);
                    break;
                case '-':
                    finalValue = firstNumber - secondNumber;
                    System.out.println(finalValue);
                    break;
                case '*':
                    finalValue = firstNumber * secondNumber;
                    System.out.println(finalValue);
                    break;
                case '/':
                    if(secondNumber == 0d) {
                        System.out.println("a number can not be divided by 0.");
                    } else {
                        finalValue = firstNumber / secondNumber;
                        System.out.println(finalValue);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Operator entered incorrectly.");
                    break;
            }

            System.out.print("Do you want another operation? (type yes to continue): ");
            answer = scanner.next();

        }

        System.out.println("Bye.");


    }
}
```

Comment: I didn't use scanner.nextDouble(); because when I type something instead of number it gives error... Calculator should not have errors you know ;d

Comment: You should avoid this behavior by using `try` to catch the `InputMismatchException` as explained [here](https://beginnersbook.com/2013/04/try-catch-in-java/).

Comment: I am just changing the code I provided to you so it catches these exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you have used `scanner.nextLine();` after `scanner.next();`

Try putting a blank statement as below to avoid the issue:

```
scanner.nextLine();
```

OR

Replace `scanner.nextLine()` with `scanner.next()`

It is working after that. Please refer below:

```
class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); // Define new Scanner

    String answer = "yes";
    double finalValue;

    while (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {

    System.out.print("Enter First Number: ");
    String firstNumber = scanner.next(); // Define first number, and ask user for input

    while (!firstNumber.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter number only: ");
        firstNumber = scanner.next();
    }

    System.out.print("Enter an operator (+, -, / or *): ");
    char operator = scanner.next().charAt(0);

    System.out.print("Enter Second Number: ");
    String secondNumber = scanner.next();

    while (!secondNumber.matches("[-+]?[0-9]*\\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?")) {
        System.out.print("Please enter number only: ");
        secondNumber = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    switch(operator) {
    case '+':
        finalValue = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber) + Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        System.out.println(finalValue);
        break;
    case '-':
        finalValue = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber) - Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        System.out.println(finalValue);
        break;
    case '*':
        finalValue = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber) * Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        System.out.println(finalValue);
        break;
    case '/':
        if(secondNumber.equals("0")) {
            System.out.println("a number can not be divided by 0.");
        } else {
        finalValue = Double.parseDouble(firstNumber) / Double.parseDouble(secondNumber);
        System.out.println(finalValue);
        }
        break;
    default:
        System.out.println("Operator entered incorrectly.");
        break;
    }

    System.out.print("Do you want another operation? (type yes to continue): ");
    answer = scanner.next();

    }

    System.out.println("Bye.");


}
}
```

[image]

But for future perspective, the best option is always to scan the expected data type like scanner.nextInt() or scanner.nextDouble()

Comment: It Works. Thanks <3

Comment: @გიორგიმაცუკატოვი Thanks. Please accept it as an answer so that it help other people as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace both `firstNumber = scanner.nextLine();` with `firstNumber = scanner.next();` and `secondNumber = scanner.nextLine();` with `secondNumber = scanner.next();`.